# Aerospike scans performance

Tags: aerospike, aql

I have a set with a bin of type unordered list. I would like to make it a sorted list using [aql set_type](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-list-ops.html#setType).

Each list contains about 15 strings, and I have 763,053,119 rows in the set.

I would like to know what would be the performance impact of such scan?
Also, how much time it will take? approximately

Thanks.

Comment: You can take a sample data set using asbackup tool to another test cluster and characterize.

Answer (score 2):

Performance impact of scans depends on quite a few things, including the cluster details (number of records per partition, number of [partition-tree-sprigs](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#partition-tree-sprigs) (and, for older versions, [partition-tree-locks](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#partition-tree-locks)) configured, if it has been sized correctly), if there are other scans running (at different priorities), the specific sensitivity for the use case (on latency specifically), etc.

The following [FAQ on scans](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/faq-scans-in-aerospike/2704) should help understand how scans are implemented which would be the best to understand potential impacts. In general, though, for well sized clusters, default settings and common workloads, the impact would not necessarily be noticeable.